# Как получить данные из бд с определенным id?

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Я нажимаю на изображение и у него айди в ссылку приходит из бд

```
<main>
        <section>
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbconnect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM city limit 5  ";
            $result = $dbcon->query($query);
            

            
            while ($myrow = $result ->fetch_assoc()) 
            {
            
            
            
            ?>

<?php  if(isset($_GET['region'])){

    
    ?>




    
    <?php  } else { ?>

    
<div class ="city">
                <div class ="logo_city">
                <a href="?content=single_city.php&city=<?=$myrow["region"];?>"> <img class="lg" src="image/<?=$myrow["logo"];?>" ></a>
        
                </div>
```

Далее в другом файле я хочу вывести информацию об этом городе

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("dbconnect.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM city where region = ";
            $result = $dbcon->query($query);
            

            
            while ($myrow = $result ->fetch_assoc()) 
            { 
                ?>
            
<img src="image/<?=$myrow["logo"];?>" alt="">
<div class ="gorod">
                                        <?=$myrow["name"];?>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class ="opisanie">
                            <?=$myrow["description"];?>
                            </div>
            <?php  }   ?>
```

В этом запросе я обращаюсь к региону т к цифры id и региона идентичны. Как мне правильно получить данные из того айди в этом файле ?